# calculation error in methods

Tags: java, methods

I have got the user input working and also my method of number of gallons working however when I try to calculate the hours of labor, what it does is it calculates it with the result of the previous calculation and not the one that I specified.

This is what I have so far. What it does is it uses the result of gallons to multiply it by 8 rather than using the square feet that the user enters. I can't seem to figure out why it does that

```
int result=gallonsofpaint(numberofsquarefeet,115,1);
System.out.println("the number of gallons of paint required is " + result);

int resultnumberofhours = hoursoflabor(numberofsquarefeet,115,8);
System.out.println("the number of hours needed are " + resultnumberofhours);

public static int gallonsofpaint(int numberofsquarefeet, int squarefeet,int paint){
    int result = numberofsquarefeet/115*1;
    return result;
}

public static int hoursoflabor(int numberofsquarefeet, int squarefeet,int labor){
    int resultnumberofhours = numberofsquarefeet/115*8;
    return resultnumberofhours;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you post what it's printing? And what did you expect? Finally, it looks like the first method has had its beginning cut off.

Comment: when i try to get the result of the number of hours of labor,so what it does is after it calculates the number of gallons of paint required for my 1st method, if the result of that method is 7..it would jump onto the next method and multiply it by 8 which is wrong.. e.g for my 2nd method if i want the number of hours i want it to do 900/115*8 and not 8*7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, the return type is `int`.

> so you 900/115 you get 7 not `7.82`

Secondly, if you want the result to have decimals, switch to double or float.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class So{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numberofsquarefeet = 900;
        int result=gallonsofpaint(numberofsquarefeet,115,1);
        System.out.println("the number of gallons of paint required is " + result);

        double resultnumberofhours = hoursoflabor(numberofsquarefeet,115,8);
        System.out.println("the number of hours needed are " + resultnumberofhours);
    }
    public static int gallonsofpaint(int numberofsquarefeet, int squarefeet, int paint) {
        int result = numberofsquarefeet / 115 * 1;
        return result;
    }

    public static double hoursoflabor(int numberofsquarefeet, int squarefeet, int labor) {
        double resultnumberofhours = (double)(numberofsquarefeet * 8 ) / 115;
        return resultnumberofhours;
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want decimals in `62.608` and want the answer to be `62`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaximiseSum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numberofsquarefeet = 900;
        int result=gallonsofpaint(numberofsquarefeet,115,1);
        System.out.println("the number of gallons of paint required is " + result);

        int resultnumberofhours = hoursoflabor(numberofsquarefeet,115,8);
        System.out.println("the number of hours needed are " + resultnumberofhours);
    }
    public static int gallonsofpaint(int numberofsquarefeet, int squarefeet, int paint) {
        int result = numberofsquarefeet / 115 * 1;
        return result;
    }

    public static int hoursoflabor(int numberofsquarefeet, int squarefeet, int labor) {
        int resultnumberofhours = (int) ((numberofsquarefeet * 8 ) / 115);
        return resultnumberofhours;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot man. the only thing i missed was int. can i ask you what that does?

Comment: takes out the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Well as per the formulas you have defined in your methods, for a specific `numberofsquarefeet`, the `resultnumberofhours` will always be `result` multiplied by 8. You can avert this by converting you field data types to floating point.